# Is there a remote shutter for Canon xsi that utilizes radio technology?

Tags: remote

I will need to remotely control my shutter (ie, take a pic) at a range that none of my current remoteless shutter remotes could come close to. I am thinking probably 50 yards about.

I heard a friend talking about the possibility of a radio frequency remote, which would eliminate the need for line of sight and prabably increase working range.

Does such a remote exist for the Canon XSi?

Comment: The youngnuo 603 also work. But I am not sure about the range on outdoors environment. http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=a9_sc_1?rh=i%3Aphoto%2Ck%3Ayoungnuo+603&keywords=youngnuo+603&ie=UTF8&qid=1448922880

Comment: I've tested my Yongnuo RF-602s to a range of 650+ ft (~200m). Be surprised if the 603s aren't at least that good. Bonus=>they're also flash triggers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this $35.95 Vello radio remote and it works very well with great range.

[Vello Radio Remote](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00653AJ7U)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Amazon [advertises a RF remote](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006BGTN64) for ~US$70, though I have not used it myself.